# Passing a Magento Job Interview

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a job interview in a few days and need some advice on what I should brush up on. I've been a web developer for 10 years but haven't worked with Magento in a few years, and even then it was only small things here and there.

What are some Magento specific topics that I should definitely know when going to a job interview? I realize this is somewhat subjective but I've only got a short amount of time to prepare so any advice here is much appreciated.